# Error with customized button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have an error:

```
2013-08-01 01:09:18.433 VstupHelper[28332:11303] -[VHMasterViewController popViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7566410
2013-08-01 01:09:18.434 VstupHelper[28332:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VHMasterViewController popViewController:]:
```

Here is my code:

```
UIButton *bt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [bt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    [bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bt addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bt];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=leftButton;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target = self.revealViewController;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
```

I'm not good at English, so I apologize if I'm hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1) You are calling `popViewController:` on what I asssume is a `UIViewController` subclass, when you should be calling it on your `UINavigationController`.

2) `popViewController:` takes a bool value for whether to animate that transition. With the action, it gets passed the sender by default.

3) You then reassign the target and action for the button (but these don't get called when you create the `UIBarButtonItem` using the `initWithCustomView:` initializer: [See docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

---

How to fix this:

1) Call a method you create for the button handler:

```
UIButton *bt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[bt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
[bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *leftButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bt];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=leftButton;
```

2) In that method, pop the view controller, or do whatever you actually want to do:

```
- (void)buttonTouched:(id)sender 
{
    [self.navigationController popViewController:YES]; 
    //Or what you assigned to the button action:
    [self.revealViewController revealToggle:(not sure what you're supposed to have here)];
}
```

Comment: other situation, i needn't this:
[bt addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

so action for button is:
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.target = self.revealViewController;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
they dont call error but dont work. help plz

Comment: When you do [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bt], this makes it so that setting .target and .action for the leftBarButtonItem does nothing. You can initialize it differently, or you can just do any actions in my -(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender method.

Comment: and what i need to do in buttontouched?
i was try and it not working:[self.revealViewController revealToggle:(sender)];

Comment: I don't know what revealToggle: expects as a parameter. I would guess a BOOL. So that line should be: [self.revealViewController revealToggle:YES];    The problem is with that code you're both popping the view controller and revealing the toggle. You probably want to only do one of these.